# String index out of range Solution? (java)

Tags: java

Getting errors running this code. Errors are 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -16.
Not sure how to fix, I've tried multiple solutions already.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Card {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your card: ");
        String number = input.next();

        if(addingDigit(number) % 10 == 0)
            System.out.println("Card is valid");
        else
            System.out.println("Card is invalid");


    }
    public static long addingDigit(String number){

        long even = 0;

        for(int i = 0, s = 2; i < number.length() - 1; i++, s *= 2){
            if(number.charAt(number.length() - s) >= '5'){
                if(number.charAt(number.length() - s) == '5')
                    even += 1;
                else if (number.charAt(number.length() - s) == '6')
                    even += 3;
                else if(number.charAt(number.length() - s) == '7')
                    even += 5;
                else if(number.charAt(number.length() - s) == '8')
                    even += 7;
                else if(number.charAt(number.length() - s) == '9')
                    even += 9;
            }

            else
                even += (number.charAt(number.length() - s) - 48);


        }

        long k = addOdd(number);
        long sumOfDigits = even + k;
        return sumOfDigits;


    }
    public static long addOdd(String number){
        long odd = 0;
        for (int i = 0, s = 1; i < number.length() - 1; i++, s += 2){
            odd += number.charAt(number.length() - s) - 48;

        }
        return odd;

    }
}
```

Comment: Think through how `charAt(...)` is going to respond vis-a-vis `s` increasing.

Comment: What are you trying to do with s? Anyway, don't subtract more than the length of the string from the length of the string when using charAt()

Comment: using s to get the even index's in the string.

Comment: How is `2, 4, 8` getting at the even indexes? Wouldn't doing ` i += 2` be a better approach and not try to subtract?

Comment: you're right. what i'm doing doesn't get me 6. was trying to not get 3 or any odd.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `number.length() - s` is in range, before trying to access the element.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop are increasing value of `s` without limited. So after some loop value of `s` will be greater then size of your string `number`. That's why you got the error. This is a bad practice.